# Custom AutoComplete component with Typescript Generics

Tags: react.js, typescript, generics

I've created my own AutoComplete form element based on `@nextui-org/autocomplete` to be able to use it along with `react-hook-form`. I am relatively new at TS, at least on generics, so I am not sure if I am overusing generics or have any mistakes really.

```
// AutoComplete.tsx

import {
  Autocomplete as NUIAutocomplete,
  AutocompleteItem as NUIAutocompleteItem,
  AutocompleteProps as NUIAutocompleteProps,
} from '@nextui-org/autocomplete';
import { CollectionChildren } from '@react-types/shared';
import React from 'react';
import { Control, FieldValues, Path, useController } from 'react-hook-form';

interface IAutoCompleteProps<T extends FieldValues, K extends object>
  extends Omit<NUIAutocompleteProps, 'children' | 'defaultItems'> {
  name: Path<T>;
  control: Control<T>;
  defaultItems?: Iterable<K>;
  children: CollectionChildren<K>;
}

const AutoComplete = <T extends FieldValues, K extends object>({
  name,
  control,
  variant = 'underlined',
  ...otherProps
}: IAutoCompleteProps<T, K>) => {
  const controller = useController({ name, control });

  return (
    <NUIAutocomplete
      aria-label={name}
      onSelectionChange={(value) => {
        console.log('value', value);
        controller.field.onChange(value);
      }}
      onClear={() => controller.field.onChange('')}
      {...controller.field}
      variant={variant}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      {otherProps.children as CollectionChildren<object>}
    </NUIAutocomplete>
  );
};

export default AutoComplete;

export const AutoCompleteItem = NUIAutocompleteItem;
```

And this is how I use it:

```
// EditClassroom.jsx

'use client';

import { Classroom, Grade } from '@prisma/client';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import { trpc } from '@/app/_trpc/client';

import { translateErrors } from '@/lib/translations';

import AutoComplete, {
  AutoCompleteItem,
} from '@/components/ui/form/AutoComplete';

interface IEditClassroomProps {
  onFinish: () => void;
  classroom?: Classroom;
}

const EditClassroom = ({ onFinish, classroom }: IEditClassroomProps) => {

  // ...

  const { data: grades } = trpc.grade.list.useQuery({});

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    reset,
    watch,

    setValue,
    control,
  } = useForm<Classroom>();

  // ...
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

      {/*...*/}

      <AutoComplete
        name={'gradeId'}
        defaultItems={grades.results}
        isRequired={true}
        selectedKey={watch('gradeId')}
        label={t('recordFields.grade')}
        errorMessage={translateErrors(tErrors, 'gradeId', errors.gradeId)}
        control={control}
      >
        {(grade) => {
          return (
            <AutoCompleteItem key={grade.id} textValue={grade.name}>
              {grade.name}
            </AutoCompleteItem>
          );
        }}
      </AutoComplete>

      {/*...*/}

    </form>
  );
};

export default EditClassroom;
```